Stopping a method when the mouse position is between certain angles around the player
I'm just wondering how I would go about doing this. I have a script where the player follows the direction of the mouse, but the problem is it is a 2d sprite, so when the mouse is directly up or down you can't see the sprite.
Honestly, this whole problem started with me being lazy and not wanting to animate a front and back.
I was thinking of stopping the lookatmouse method when the mouse position is between two angles, front and back, preventing the sprite from disappearing and then starting the method when the mouse has left the zone, but as I said I'm not sure how to do this and would be grateful for any help.
Also any other ideas to stop the player disappearing would be great, I don't know how other games would do this.
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnSpeed = 6f;

    public TrailRenderer trailRenderer;
    public float trailThreshold = 200f; //How fast player needs to spin to enable the trail

    private Quaternion prevRotation;

    private void Start()
    {
        prevRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (controller.isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = transform.right * horizontal + transform.forward * vertical;
        moveDirection.Normalize(); //Consistent movement in all directions

        if (moveDirection.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            controller.Move(moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        Lookatmouse();

        // Calculate angular velocity
        float angle = Quaternion.Angle(prevRotation, transform.rotation);
        float angularVelocity = angle / Time.deltaTime;
        // Update previous rotation
        prevRotation = transform.rotation;

        trailRenderer.enabled = angularVelocity > trailThreshold;
    }

    void Lookatmouse()
    {
        Plane playerplane = new Plane(Vector3.up, transform.position);
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        float hitdist;
        if (playerplane.Raycast(ray, out hitdist))
        {
            Vector3 targetpoint = ray.GetPoint(hitdist);
            Quaternion targetrotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetpoint - transform.position);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetrotation, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}

